How can I open TestingSettingsActivity in Android 11 and above?
My code
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity");
startActivity(intent);

My error

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity }

I just want to open this hidden advanced scream network settings on my app.
you can see here a image of the hidden android config

The Settings app is heavily customized by many device manufacturers. There is no requirement for this activity to exist on any given device, let alone be launchable by third-party apps.

it's a function from android, but on android 11+ I've received  Permission Denial, so this function existis, I just do not have permission

"so this function existis" -- this activity might exist on the few devices that you have tested. There are tens of thousands of devices. This activity does not have to exist on any of them and almost certainly will not exist on all of them.

but this is not the problem, the problem is the "Permission Denial" when I try to open it in a device that this option exists. i don't have problem if it exists or not, I just wanna open it when it exists

There is no requirement for that activity to be exported; if it is not exported, third-party apps like yours cannot start it. IIRC, this will result in a SecurityException. So, it is not merely a question of "when it exists", but when the device manufacturer was sloppy enough to allow the activity to be started by third-party apps.

Is there any way around this case? there are some apps that can do this like "force 4G" on playstore.
